# Hpple not able to identify <tr> tag

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, hpple

Hello I ank using this is my current path

```
NSString *XpathQ2 = @"//table[@class='grid']/tbody";
```

when i try to change it to

```
NSString *XpathQ2 = @"//table[@class='grid']/tbody/tr";
```

or

```
NSString *XpathQ2 = @"//table[@class='grid']/tbody/tr[4]";
```

the code outputs Nodes was nil

Comment: did you add only /tr in the same method?

Comment: yea, everting remained the same, I know the html data is correct all i added was the tr tag and the output became nil

Comment: is nil in nslog or other?

Comment: The nil is in the NSlog showing node was nil